# Get data from WTForms form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

How do I get the data from a WTForms form after submitting it? I want to get the email entered in the form.

```
class ApplicationForm(Form):
    email = StringField()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ApplicationForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('index')

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.email }}
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each field has a [`data`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.data) attribute containing the processed data.

```
the_email = form.email.data
```

Working with form data is described in the [getting started doc](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/crash_course.html#using-forms).

Answer (score 3):

The most probable place for you to do things with the Form.attrs is in the `index` function. I have added some conditional guards on the method param. You want to do different things if they are using `GET` or `POST` as well. There are other ways to do all of this but I didn't want to change too much at once. But you should think about it clearly this way. If I have no form data because I've just made the initial request, I'm going to be using `GET`. Once I render the form in the template, I'm going to be sending a `POST` (as you can see in the top of your template). So I need those two cases dealt with firstly.

Then, once the form is rendered and returned I will have data or no data. So dealing with the data is going to happen in the `POST` branch of the controller.

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    errors = '' 

    form = ApplicationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_submitted():
            print "Form successfully submitted"
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            flash('Success!')
            # Here I can assume that I have data and do things with it.
            # I can access each of the form elements as a data attribute on the
            # Form object.
            flash(form.name.data, form.email.data)
            # I could also pass them onto a new route in a call.
            # You probably don't want to redirect to `index` here but to a 
            # new view and display the results of the form filling.
            # If you want to save state, say in a DB, you would probably
            # do that here before moving onto a new view.
            return redirect('index')
        else:  # You only want to print the errors since fail on validate
            print(form.errors)  
            return render_template('index.html',
                                   title='Application Form',
                                   form=form)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', 
                               title='Application Form',
                                   form=form)
```

To help, I'm adding a simple example from some of my working code. You should be able to follow it given your code and my walk through.

```
def create_brochure():
    form = CreateBrochureForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not form.validate():
            flash('There was a problem with your submission. Check the error message below.')
            return render_template('create-brochure.html', form=form)
        else:
            flash('Succesfully created new brochure: {0}'.format(form.name.data))
            new_brochure = Brochure(form.name.data,
                                    form.sales_tax.data,
                                    True,
                                    datetime.datetime.now(),
                                    datetime.datetime.now())
            db.session.add(new_brochure)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('brochures')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('create-brochure.html', form=form)
```